# Take only some value from JavaFX ObservableList

Tags: java, charts, javafx-2, javafx

I need to build a

```
LineChart<Number,Number>
```

I had the data stored in

```
ObservableList<MyData>
```

`MyData` had 4 variable, all of it are `int`. Let just say the variable in `MyData` are:  `No1, No2, No3, No4`.

Next, I need to build

```
LineChart<Number,Number>
```

and I need only `No1` and `No2` variable, but I don't know how to take that value from `ObservableList`,  Now I just use `XYChart.Data` to add new data to `XYChart.Series` of my `LineChart<Number,Number>` like this:

```
private static XYChart.Series dataLineChart = new XYChart.Series();
public static void updateDataChart(){
    dataLineChart.getData().addAll(
                new XYChart.Data(3,15),
                new XYChart.Data(7,20)
            );
}
```

If only I can take the value from `ObservableList` I can just simply use :

```
private static XYChart.Series dataLineChart = new XYChart.Series();
public static void updateDataChart(){
    dataLineChart.getData().addAll(
                myObservableList
            );
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem ?

Comment: It seems for me, there is no better solution, than to convert data from your observable array list, into array list, used as parameter of data of chart...

Comment: @AlexanderKirov : Yeah, but it just so wasteful, i already had the data but still need to convert it to another type of list to use them :(

Comment: I've created an RFE : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30059, you can track its progress and discussion on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new list anyway. It's not a problem, it's fast and only a bit of new memory will be used (only for handlers, not for objects):

If you know positions of required items you can use `List#subList()` method.

```
private static XYChart.Series dataLineChart = new XYChart.Series();
public static void updateDataChart(){
    dataLineChart.getData().addAll(
            myObservableList.subList(0,2);
    );
}
```

If items are not consequent, you may  to create new list in one line:

```
ObservableList<String> sublist = FXCollections.observableArrayList( 
                     myObservableList.get(3), myObservableList.get(5) );
```

Also you may save on new list if you use your condition to filter old list into new directly in update method:

```
public static void updateDataChart(){
    for (MyData data : myObservableList) {
        if ( data.isLucky() ) // or whatever is your condition
            dataLineChart.getData().add(data);
    }
}
```